# If two integrationflows are passed to one general MessageHandler class, is it thread safe? in Spring Integration DSL

Tags: multithreading, apache-kafka, spring-integration-dsl, message-handlers

I have **two IntegrationFlows**
both receive messages from Apache Kafka

**first IntegrationFlow** - in the input channel, Consumer1(concurrency=4) reads **topic_1**

**second IntegrationFlow** - in the input channel, Consumer2(concurrency=4) reads **topic_2**

but these **two IntegrationFlows**, send messages to the **output channel**, where **one common class** **MyMessageHandler** is specified

like this:

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow sendFromQueueFlow1(MyMessageHandler message) {
    return IntegrationFlows
            .from(Kafka
                    .messageDrivenChannelAdapter(consumerFactory1, "topic_1")
                    .configureListenerContainer(configureListenerContainer_priority1)
                    )
            .handle(message)
            .get();
}


@Bean
public IntegrationFlow sendFromQueueFlow2(MyMessageHandler message) {
    return IntegrationFlows
            .from(Kafka
                    .messageDrivenChannelAdapter(consumerFactory2, "topic_2")
                    .configureListenerContainer(configureListenerContainer_priority2)
                    )
            .handle(message)
            .get();
}
```

class **MyMessageHandler** have method **send(message)**, this method passes messages further to another service

```
class MyMessageHandler {
            
    protected void handleMessageInternal(Message<?> message)
    {
        String postResponse = myService.send(message); // remote service calling
        msgsStatisticsService.sendMessage(message, postResponse);
        // *******
    }
}
```

inside each IntegrationFlow, **4 Consumer-threads are working** (
a total of 8 threads), and they all go to one class MyMessageHandler,
into one metod **send()**

**what problems could there be?**
two IntegrationFlow, do they see each other when they pass a message to one common class??? do I need to provide thread safety in the MyMessageHandler class??? Do I need to prepend the send () method with the word **synchronized**???

But what if we make a third IntegrationFlow?

so that only one IntegrationFlow can pass messages through itself to the MyMessageHandler class? then would it be thread safe? example:

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow sendFromQueueFlow1() {
return IntegrationFlows
        .from(Kafka
                .messageDrivenChannelAdapter(consumerFactory1, "topic_1")
                .configureListenerContainer(configureListenerContainer_priority1)
        )
        .channel(**SOME_CHANNEL**())
        .get();
```

}

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow sendFromQueueFlow2() {
return IntegrationFlows
        .from(Kafka
                .messageDrivenChannelAdapter(consumerFactory2, "topic_2")
                .configureListenerContainer(configureListenerContainer_priority2)
        )
        .channel(**SOME_CHANNEL**())
        .get();
```

}

```
@Bean
public MessageChannel **SOME_CHANNEL**() {

    DirectChannel channel = new DirectChannel();
    return channel;
 }

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow sendALLFromQueueFlow(MyMessageHandler message) {

return IntegrationFlows
        .from(**SOME_CHANNEL**())
        .handle(message)
        .get();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make your handler code thread-safe.

Using `synchronized` on the whole method you will effectively disable the concurrency.

It's better to use thread-safe techniques - no mutable fields or use limited synchronization blocks, just around critical code.

Comment: Thanks. I would like to really not use the word synchronized. May slow down message traffic.
And what if we make a third IntegrationFlow, which reads Channel1, and the output channel in the MyMessageHandler class, and let the two IntegrationFlows transfer Channel1 to this one channel ?

Comment: It doesn't matter how many flows you have; the fact that you have concurrency > 1 in even one flow means you need to ensure all of the downstream code is thread-safe. Learn how to write stateless classes.